# Regarding GKE optimised image hardening

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, hardening

We tried to harden the gke optimized image (gke-1.15.11) for our cluster. We took an ssh into the node instance and made the cis porposed changes in the `/home/kubernetes/kubelet-config.yaml` file and ran kubebench to check if all the conditions have passed around 8 condtions failed these where the exact conditions we changed in the file. But, then we made the exact argument changes in `/etc/default/kubernetes` and ran `kubebench` again the conditions passed. But, when we restarted the instance we all the changes we made in the `/ect/default/kubernetes` file where gone. Can someone let me know where we are going wrong or is there any other path where we have to make the cis benchmark suggested entries

Comment: which exactly image type you are using for the nodes of your GKE cluster?  cos/cos_containerd/ubuntu/ubuntu_containerd ?

Answer (score 1):

GKE doesn't support user-provided node images as of April 2020. [Recommended option](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#modifications) is to create your own `DaemonSet` with host filesystem writes and/or host services restart to propagate all the required changes.